# Are the same constants independent and identically distributed?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For independent and identically distributed variables, we know that each variable is independent of each other and obeys the same distribution. I want to know if a constant sequence also has such properties?

For example, we assume that there is a sequence ${X_1,X_2,X_3....,X_n}$, in which each variable is a constant, that is

$$X_1=X_2=X_3=...X_n=C$$

(where $C$ is a constant, like $C=5$).

So are $X_1,X_2,X_3,...X_n$ i.i.d?

Comment: clearly the $X_i$'s are identically distributed, so you need to show that they are independent. Apply the definition of independence and see what you get

Comment: Try to prove the following statement: constant random variable (it is better to say that $\mathsf P\{X = \mathsf E[X]\} = 1$) and any other one are independent

Comment: Yes, in principal they are. If $X$ and $Y$ are rv's on the same probability space and at least one of them is degenerated then $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Just apply the definition of independency to verify.

Comment: I second Stratos's respnse.  Before asking this here, Cathy should write down the definition of "independent" and see what happens in this case.  Only if she gets stuck on that should she ask us, and include her computations.